# php script mailer modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I submit my form using modal in bootstrap
How can I make this work with dismissal message and not closing the modal?

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-custom">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body text-center">

                    <form class="form-inline requestaccessForm" role="form" name="requestaccessForm">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="First Name">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="request_last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="request_email" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" id="requestformSubmit" class="btn btn-green">Submit</button>

                    </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $myemail = 'dummyemail@email.com';
 if (isset($_POST['request_first_name'])) {
 $request_first_name = strip_tags($_POST['request_first_name']);
 $request_last_name = strip_tags($_POST['request_last_name']);
 $request_email = strip_tags($_POST['request_email']);

  echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks!       
  Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
  echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$request_first_name."<br>"; 
  echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$request_last_name."<br>";  
  echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$request_email."<br>"; 


 $to = $myemail;
 $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $request_first_name";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
 " Here are the details:\n Name: $request_first_name \n ".
 "Email: $request_email\n";
 $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $request_email";
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 }?>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button#requestformSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php", // 
                data: $('form.requestaccessForm').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want to display the successful message inside the modal?

Comment: yes without closing the modal. also it's not submitting successfully

Comment: Why don't you use the success handler of the `$.ajax` request?

Comment: I actually don't know how to code using ajax. I just referred to this link and put it on my site http://untame.net/2013/05/how-to-build-a-modal-contact-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-with-php-ajax/

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you have to take some steps first..

1. Add a `div` inside the modal which will serve as the success message container.

   Before closing the `<div class="modal-body text-center">` add the following code:

   ```
   ...
   <div id="successMessage"/></div>
   ...
   ```
2. Change the `success` handler of the `$.ajax` request to add the dismissal/success message into the `div` created in the previous step.

   Add the following code to your `$.ajax` `success` handler:

   ```
   ...
   success: function(msg){
                $("#successMessage").html(msg);
   },
   ...
   ```
3. Prevent default actions from the button click so that the modal will not be closed after the request.

   Add the following line at the end of your jQuery `click` function:

   ```
   return false;
   ```

So your jQuery code will look something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#requestformSubmit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php", // 
            data: $('form.requestaccessForm').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#successMessage").html(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Hi. I getting a failure message. But I already make some changes on the current code

Comment: Hey! Somehow it helps me :) thanks a lot! I just have some code added but some of your code helps. :)